# Adjective for being a superlative in something

Tags: single-word-request

Recently I had a conversation with a friend, who told me about how he thought he would be the fastest of his university to get his bachelor's degree.
I answered that I find this pretty presumptuous and would never assume of myself to be the best in anything out of such a large group of candidates.

To that he countered, that he didn't say "der Beste" but rather "der Schnellste".

I knew what he said, but couldn't think of a single adjective that describes being a superlative in anything (positive or negative).

I would like to say:

> "Ich würde nicht annehmen, dass ich in irgendetwas [gesuchtes Adjektiv] bin."

Comment: I just removed the formatting as source code - there is no automatic line break, making the essential text hard to impossible to read, especially on mobile devices.

Comment: Ist dir bewusst, dass die meisten Leute, die hier Fragen beantworten, deutsche Muttersprachler sind? In deinem Profil steht, dass du aus Deutschland bist, daher rate ich mal, dass deine Muttersprache ebenfalls Deutsch ist. Du stellst eine Frage über einen Aspekt der deutschen Sprache, und du tust das in einem Deutsch-Forum. Welches wäre wohl die beste Sprache, in der du deine Frage formulieren solltest? Kleiner Tipp: »Englisch« ist nicht die richtige Antwort. Siehe auch: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: 1. Der Großteil der Fragen, die ich hier sehe ist auf Englisch. 2. In dem Link, den du angegeben hast, steht explizit, dass beides erlaubt ist, implizit, dass auch beides gleichermaßen genutzt wird und außerdem die Reichweite auf Englisch höher ist. Letzteres ist auch mein vorrangiger Beweggrund.

Comment: "am besten"? "am schnellsten"? "am tollsten"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mein Vorschlag (zwar auch kein Superlativ, aber das betrachte auch nicht als zwingend) benötigt zwei Worte:

> weit überdurchschnitttlich

im negativen Fall *unterdurchschnittlich*. Der Vorteil ist, dass man damit nicht behauptet, der Inhaber des entsprechenden Weltrekords zu sein, was den Nutzerkreis doch stark einschränken würde.

Comment: Das beantwortet zwar ganz streng genommen nicht genau die Frage, ist aber für die Anforderungen ein genau so gut ausreichendes Konstrukt, also werde ich es als richtige Antwort markieren.

Answer (score 0):

This one would be my favourite:

> Ich würde nicht annehmen, dass ich in irgendetwas **extrem** bin.

Samples:

> extrem schnell / langsam
>
> extrem gut / schlecht
>
> extrem geschickt / ungeschickt
>
> extrem stark / schwach

In math we have the [*Extremwert*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Extremwert) which is either a minimum or a maximum.

Also possible (without fitting very well):

> extremst (so called [Elativ](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Elativ))
>
> maximal
>
> höchstgradig (constructed from *hochgradig*)

Comment: Finde ich unpassend, denn das ist nur Komparativ, kein Superlativ.

Comment: @Robert Das ist *kein* Komparativ. Superlativ allerdings auch nicht. Positiv.

Comment: @tofro Richtig. Das war ungeschickt formuliert. Ich wollte sagen, dass "extrem" in der Umgangssprache zur Steigerung verwendet wird, aber kein Superlativ ist.